# Complete the proof of $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{e^{-x^2/2}x^{2n} dx} = \sqrt{2\pi} \frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!} $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, summation

What I already know is that if $L(s) := \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{e^{sx}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} dx}=\sqrt{2\pi}e^{\frac{s^2}{2}}$, then $L^{(2n)}(0)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}x^{2n} dx}$. So far, that is easy to understand but at the last step the author wrote:

The exponential series yields:
$$L(s) =\sqrt{2\pi}e^{\frac{s^2}{2}}=\sqrt{2\pi}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{s^{2n}}{2^nn!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty L^{(2n)}(0)\frac{s^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$
And the answer can be derived by solving for $L^{(2n)}(0)$.

However, I can't figure out how the last step came out. Thank you for any help! (The original answer is attached below)[image]

[image]

Comment: Just equate coefficients of $s^{2n}$ on the two sides.

Comment: Hi @geetha290krm thank you but can you be more specific? I just can't think through how the $L^{(2n)}(0)$ appears in the last equation.

Comment: You can just do the change of variable $x\to \sqrt x$ and use the formula for the Gamma function

Comment: “The last step” is a bit ambiguous. Do you mean why $$L(s)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty L^{(2n)}(0)\frac{s^{2n}}{(2n)!}\quad ?$$ This is the Taylor series expansion of $L(s)$ as an even function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reduction Formaula**
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_n & =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} x^{2 n} d x \\
& =-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^{2 n-1} d\left(e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\right) \\
& =-\left[x^{2 n-1} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\right]_{-\infty}^{\infty}+(2 n-1) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^{2 n-2} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} d x \\
& =(2 n-1) I_{n-1} \\
& =(2 n-1)(2 n-3) \cdots(1) I_0 \\
& =\frac{(2 n) !}{2 ^n n !} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} d x\\&=\frac{(2 n) !}{2^n n !} \sqrt{2 \pi},
\end{aligned}
$$
which is a bit different from the answer of OP.

Comment: Thank you! You are right and the OP is updated.